# Symfony2 - Get return result from call service option

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get the return result from a method perform by the call option of service. So
My service.xml :

```
<service id="myService" class="serviceClass">
    <argument type="service" id="..."/>
    <argument type="service" id="..."/>        
    <call method="myReturnProblem"/>
</service>
```

My service method :

```
function serviceMethod(){
    ...
    $foo = "bar"
    var_dump($foo);
    return true;
}
```

My Controller :

```
function sampleAction(){
    ...
    $this->get('my_Service');
    return Response...
}
```

So, i can see with the var_dump that the method is running like i hope but i don't know how can i get the return true(same problem if i try to get $foo or what else) .

Right now if i make :

```
if($this->('my_Service))
```

it doesn't work cause it doesn't contains the result. To get it i have to make something like

```
if($this->('my_Service')->serviceMethod())
```

but it runs the serviceMethod twice.

I wanted make something like :

```
if($this->get('my_Service')){}
```

Any idea ? thanks.

Comment: `if($this->get('my_Service')->serviceMethod())` typo?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure to understand what do you mean but,    if($this->get('my_Service')->serviceMethod())

will execute serviceMethod(which is already executed by the call option) but in this case return the result(here true according to my sample)

Answer (score 0):

What you did is called **Setter Injection**, references available [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection)

As the name suggests, it is for injecting a service into another service, not for returning value.

To achieve a result purpose, you should create a regular method inside the service to process values and then return the result.

```
public function myMethod()
{
    ...
    $foo = "bar";
    var_dump($foo);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I have try to process within my service constructor and add the scope but it returns the same result as with the setter injection(not the result i wish but the service object).
About the regular method, i have to call it in my controller to get the result. I'm wondering a way to get it just by calling the service.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I thought service with scope `prototype` will work just like create a new object instance. I updated my answer, removing that part. I think there is no other way except call a regular method.